# Fitting a distribution to sample data

Tags: distributions, goodness-of-fit

I have completely modified this post for the sake of clarity. To Whuber and David, thank you guys for your posts.

I want to perform a MC Simulation to see what will, more likely, be the tendency in the distribution of vessels by TEU Capacity (if there is going to be more vessels in the 1000-2000 TEU range, or in the 300 - 4000 TEU range, etc.).

But to do the MC Simulation I need to generate random numbers from a specific distribution and I do not want to assume normality or lognormality or any other distribution if I do not do the goodness of fit check first. The thing is, what how would I go around the  distribution fitting taking into account the number of vessels assigned to each TEU Range Class?

```
CLASS                   Count of Vessel          FREQ
13,000.01 - 14,000 TEUS       22             25%
8,000.01 - 9,000 TEUS         19             21%
4,000.01 - 5,000 TEUS         17             19%
6,000.01 - 7,000 TEUS          9             10%
5,000.01 - 6,000 TEUS          6              7%
9,000.01 - 10,000 TEUS         5              6%
1,000.01 - 2,000 TEUS          4              4%
3,000.01 - 4,000 TEUS          4              4%
16,000.01 - 16,500 TEUS        2              2%
2,000.01 - 3,000 TEUS          1              1%

Grand Total 89
```

Comment: The example is mystifying because there is no apparent relationship between `Number of Vessels` and `Frequency`. The question itself is puzzling because it is not clear which variable you want to fit a distribution to, nor what the purpose the MC simulation will be. Could you please edit your question to explain these points?

Comment: You say "frequency is just the percentage of the total." Are there any bins missing? Given a total of 12450 ships, I get the frequencies: 8%, 24%, 22% and 46% for the respective given bins. Also, your given frequencies don't add up to 100. I tried assuming that at least one of the frequencies was accurate (as opposed to a rounded estimate) and used that to extrapolate a total to work off of, but I haven't been able to reproduce anything resembling your numbers.

Comment: Hello WHuber and David Marx, thank you guys for your comments. That was not the real dataset, that was just an example of the structure of my dataset. I want to fit a distribution that can, in a decent way, the behavior of my data. I´d like to fit the distribution to the frequency and number of vessels falling into the several different TEUs categories. Please guys let ke

Comment: If your table is typical why are the data aggregated? This is not my field but it seems likely that the capacity is known precisely for every ship, in which case you could bootstrap from the known distribution. Note that your restriction does bite you: if you don't want to specify a particular parameterised distribution, fair enough, but is there a third alternative beyond resampling the data?

Answer (score 1):

You're presenting data aggregated into bins of effectively fixed width, so you basically have a histogram to work with.

```
# sample data
vesselsize = c(13e3, 8e3,4e3, 6e3, 5e3, 9e3, 1e3, 3e3, 16e3, 2e3) # lower bound of each bin.
freq = c(.25, .21, .19, .10, .7, .6, .4, .4, .2, .1)

# histogram
plot(vesselsize, freq, type='h')
```

[image]

If you *really* want to do a MC simulation, here's a really, really dirty solution you could try:

```
# reverse-engineered pseudo-sample
N=1e4
test = sample(vesselsize, size=N, replace=T, prob=freq)
BW=2*density(test)$bw # doubling bandwidth since each bucket of values
                      # is concentrated at a single point (which would
                      # give us very sharp peaks with the default bw)
plot(density(test, bw=BW))
```

[image]

NB: For each bin, we really only know that the vessels in that bin are at minimum the size of the lower bound of the bin, so instead of making any distributional assumptions about the bin (e.g. drawing uniform samples across the full range of the bin) I just sample from the lower bound of the bins.

I'm not sure how helpful this approach is to you, but it sounds like you're looking to build up a "fake" dataset, so here's one way you could accomplish that.